# Sharing data across directives design pattern in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to design the interaction between four directives.

**Directive 1**: Creates an HTML form with field for `student_id`.

**Directive 2**: When student_id is set/changed in *directive1*, this directive downloads student(s) information from the database. The purpose of directive2 is to make sure data is downloaded once and used by other directives.

**Directive 3**: When a student_data is downloaded by directive2, this directive creates a table of the student's performance.

**Directive 4**: When a student_data is downloaded by directive2, this directive creates a chart of the student's performance.

Directive2/3/4 are pretty generic and I will need them in multiple pages.

Directive 2 sends a request to server so data won't be available for directive3/4 immediately. The data in the form generated by directive 1 may be modified, in this case, all linked directives need to be reevaluated.

What is proper design for this scenario? Should **they all be nested** like below?

```
 <d1><d2><d3></d3><d4></d4></d2></d1>  (scope:require ...)
```

Should I use a **service** with **$broadcast/$on** or modify the **$rootScope.** or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using service should be the cleaner way to do it. Polluting `rootScope` unnecessarily should be avoided.
Create a basic service with setters and getters and inject in each directive of yours.
Since service is singleton, you will have the same data available across all the directives.

Comment: As a note, using Service implies I need to use $on/$emit to broadcast data changes across the system, while $rootScope has this built in.

Comment: you don't necessarily need it, but yes its better to emit and catch events, rather than using lots of watches.